# Reduce cluttering in a VPN initialization dance implementation (html, xml extraction and api calls) in Go

Tags: html, go, api, xml, form

I'm still rather new to Go and I wanted to convert a part of a Python script I wrote a while ago to perform the VPN initialization dance (basically a set of API calls + parsing to fetch an auth cookie which will be then passed to open-connect application via a spawn)

The script below works, but I feel it's overly redundant, verbose, it's almost four times bigger than my original Python code.

I thought about using [Colly](http://go-colly.org) but can't manage to have something smooth (Colly involves using a lot of callbacks which makes the code looks ever more convoluted and hard to follow).

I would like to have a review andsee if I can make my script below, shorter, clearer and without much clutter. If there are good Go practices that can be applied, please let me know.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "github.com/antchfx/xmlquery"
    "github.com/levigross/grequests"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func inputClearText(prompt string) string {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    print(prompt + ": ")
    scanner.Scan()
    return scanner.Text()
}

func inputPassword(prompt string) string {
    print(prompt + ": ")
    password, _ := terminal.ReadPassword(int(os.Stdin.Fd()))
    println()
    return string(password)
}

func sessionReq(session *grequests.Session, httpMethod string, url string, ro *grequests.RequestOptions) (*grequests.Response, error) {
    switch strings.ToUpper(httpMethod) {
    case http.MethodOptions:
        return session.Options(url, ro)
    case http.MethodHead:
        return session.Head(url, ro)
    case http.MethodGet:
        return session.Get(url, ro)
    case http.MethodPost:
        return session.Post(url, ro)
    case http.MethodPut:
        return session.Put(url, ro)
    case http.MethodPatch:
        return session.Patch(url, ro)
    case http.MethodDelete:
        return session.Delete(url, ro)
    default:
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("httpMethod %s not supported", httpMethod)
    }
}

func submitForm(session *grequests.Session, html string, formId string, inputOverrides map[string]string) (*grequests.Response, error) {
    if inputOverrides == nil {
        inputOverrides = map[string]string{}
    }

    doc, e := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(strings.NewReader(html))
    if e != nil {
        return nil, e
    }

    form := doc.Find("form" + formId)
    if len(form.Nodes) < 1 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("form %s was not found", formId)
    }
    if len(form.Nodes) > 1 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("too many form with id %s have been found", formId)
    }

    formMethod, isFound := form.Attr("method")
    if !isFound {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("form %s has no \"method\" attribute", formId)
    }

    formAction, isFound := form.Attr("action")
    if !isFound {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("form %s has no \"action\" attribute", formId)
    }

    inputs := form.Find("input")
    formData := map[string]string{}
    inputs.Each(func(i int, selection *goquery.Selection) {
        inputType, isFound := selection.Attr("type")
        if !isFound || (inputType == "submit") {
            return
        }

        inputName, isFound := selection.Attr("name")
        if !isFound {
            return
        }

        if overrideValue, isContained := inputOverrides[inputName]; isContained {
            formData[inputName] = overrideValue
        } else {
            value, isFound := selection.Attr("value")
            if !isFound {
                return
            }
            formData[inputName] = value
        }
    })
    requestOptions := &grequests.RequestOptions{
        Data:      formData,
    }
    return sessionReq(session, formMethod, formAction, requestOptions)
}

func main() {

    username := inputClearText("Username")
    password := inputPassword("Password")
    smartphoneCode := inputClearText("Non-expired Smartphone App Code")

    const vpnPortalUrl = "some vpn address"
    vpnPreloginUrl := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s/global-protect/prelogin.esp", vpnPortalUrl)

    requestOptions := &grequests.RequestOptions{UserAgent: "PAN GlobalProtect"}
    session := grequests.NewSession(requestOptions)
    vpnPreloginXml, e := session.Get(vpnPreloginUrl, session.RequestOptions)
    if e != nil {
        println("Error: " + e.Error())
        return
    }
    if vpnPreloginXml == nil {
        println("VPN Prelogin xml is empty")
        return
    }

    vpnPreloginXmlRoot, e := xmlquery.Parse(strings.NewReader(vpnPreloginXml.String()))
    if e != nil {
        println("VPN Prelogin xml cannot be parsed: " + e.Error())
        return
    }

    samlRequestNode := xmlquery.FindOne(vpnPreloginXmlRoot, "//saml-request")
    samlRequestRaw, e := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(samlRequestNode.InnerText())
    if e != nil {
        println("SAML Request could not be decoded: " + e.Error())
        return
    }

    overrideValues := map[string]string{}
    res, e := submitForm(session, string(samlRequestRaw), "#myform", overrideValues)
    if e != nil {
        println("SAML Request could not be decoded: " + e.Error())
        return
    }
    if res == nil {
        println("SAML Request has returned empty")
        return
    }

    overrideValues = map[string]string{}
    overrideValues["username"] = username
    overrideValues["password"] = password
    res, e = submitForm(session, res.String(), "#kc-form-login", overrideValues)
    if e != nil {
        println("Login has failed: " + e.Error())
        return
    }
    if res == nil {
        println("Login Request has returned empty")
        return
    }

    overrideValues = map[string]string{}
    overrideValues["totp"] = smartphoneCode
    res, e = submitForm(session, res.String(), "#kc-totp-login-form", overrideValues)
    if e != nil {
        println("OTP code has failed: " + e.Error())
        return
    }
    if res == nil {
        println("OTP code Request has returned empty")
        return
    }

    overrideValues = map[string]string{}
    res, e = submitForm(session, res.String(), "", overrideValues)
    if e != nil {
        println("Prelogin-Cookie request has failed: " + e.Error())
        return
    }
    if res == nil {
        println("Prelogin-Cookie request has returned empty")
        return
    }
    preloginCookieHeader, isFound := res.Header["Prelogin-Cookie"]

    if !isFound {
        println("Prelogin-Cookie cannot be found")
        return
    }

    vpnGetConfigUrl := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s/global-protect/getconfig.esp", vpnPortalUrl)

    vpnGetConfigData := map[string]string{}
    vpnGetConfigData["user"] = username
    vpnGetConfigData["prelogin-cookie"] = strings.Join(preloginCookieHeader, ", ")

    res, e = session.Post(vpnGetConfigUrl, &grequests.RequestOptions{Data: vpnGetConfigData} )
    if e != nil {
        println("Get VPN configuration has failed: " + e.Error())
        return
    }
    if res == nil {
        println("VPN configuration has returned empty")
        return
    }

    vpnConfigXmlRoot, e := xmlquery.Parse(strings.NewReader(res.String()))
    if e != nil {
        println("VPN configuration XML cannot be parsed: " + e.Error())
        return
    }
    portalUserAuthCookie := xmlquery.FindOne(vpnConfigXmlRoot, "//portal-userauthcookie").InnerText()
    println(portalUserAuthCookie)
}
```